# Want a solution to find above limit and below limit counts separately using single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two predefined tolerance limits in another table(A), i want to calculate how many values which are above the tolerance limit and below the tolerance limit using 'Single Query' INTO two different variables using data in current table(B). Is it possible using single query ? There is also a very important where clause in the same query which is for non unique int column called referenceNo.

### Example:

Tolerance 1 from **Table A** : 4
Tolerance 2 from **Table A** : 6
referenceNo and Data Value from **Table B**:

```
+-------------+------------+
| referenceNo | Data Value |
+-------------+------------+
|         227 |          7 |
|         227 |          2 |
|         227 |          4 |
|         227 |          5 |
|         227 |          9 |
|         228 |          5 |
|         228 |          1 |
|         228 |          0 |
|         228 |          8 |
|         228 |          6 |
+-------------+------------+
```

i am expecting output COUNT(*) for below Tolerance 1 and COUNT(*) for above Tolerance 2 INTO @BelowTolerance1Count and @AboveTolerance2Count.
Like:

```
Output: (For referenceNo = 227)
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| @BelowTolerance1Count | @AboveTolerance2Count |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|                     1 |                     2 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
Output: (For referenceNo = 228)
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| @BelowTolerance1Count | @AboveTolerance2Count |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|                     2 |                     1 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code example will help you understand how to do this:

```
SELECT 
   referenceNo,
   SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BELOW_4
   SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE > 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABOVE_6
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY referenceNo
```

> Note:  This solution solves for all reference numbers, not just a specific number.  This is often how SQL works since it is set based.

You could make a view

```
CREATE VIEW SOLVE_PROBLEM AS
SELECT 
   referenceNo,
   SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE < 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BELOW_4
   SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE > 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ABOVE_6
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY referenceNo
```

And then use it

```
SELECT * FROM SOLVE_PROBLEM WHERE referenceNo = 227

SELECT * FROM SOLVE_PROBLEM WHERE referenceNo = 228
```

or even

```
SELECT 
  @BelowTolerance1Count = BELOW_4, 
  @AboveTolerance2Count = ABOVE_6
FROM SOLVE_PROBLEM 
WHERE referenceNo = 228
```